# c# not all code paths return a value error

Tags: c#, .net, function, stringbuilder

I get the following error in c# with this code
"not all code paths return a value"
I am trying to create a programming language using it.
any help is greatly appreciated.

```
private Expr ParseExpr()
{
    if (this.index == this.tokens.Count)
    {
        throw new System.Exception("expected expression, got EOF");
    }
    if (this.tokens[this.index] is Text.StringBuilder)
    {
        string Value = ((Text.StringBuilder)this.tokens[this.index++]).ToString();
        StringLiteral StringLiteral = new StringLiteral();
        StringLiteral.Value = Value;
    }
    else if (this.tokens[this.index] is int)
    {
        int intvalue = (int)this.tokens[this.index++];
        IntLiteral intliteral = new IntLiteral();
        intliteral.Value = intvalue;
        return intliteral;    
    }
    else if (this.tokens[this.index] is string)
    {
        string Ident = (string)this.tokens[this.index++];
        Variable var = new Variable();
        var.Ident = Ident;
        return var;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new System.Exception("expected string literal, int literal, or variable");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to rename your `Variable var`. var is a reserved keyword in some recent versions of C#.

Comment: Don't forget to return value at the end of your function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you've forgotten to return value there:

```
 if (this.tokens[this.index] is Text.StringBuilder)
    {
        string Value = ((Text.StringBuilder)this.tokens[this.index++]).ToString();
        StringLiteral StringLiteral = new StringLiteral();
        StringLiteral.Value = Value;
        //return Anything
    }
```

You also should return value at the end of your function.

Comment: Thanks :) I cant believe I didn't see that!

Comment: @Gabe instead of saying thank to every one. Simply mark the answer that fixed your question

Comment: @im_a_noob sorry I had to wait ten minutes and after that I had to go somewhere so I'm only back now :P

Comment: @Gabe that cool just saying becuse many new user don't mark answer

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to return anything in the second if:

```
if (this.tokens[this.index] is Text.StringBuilder)
{
    string Value = ((Text.StringBuilder)this.tokens[this.index++]).ToString();
    StringLiteral StringLiteral = new StringLiteral();
    StringLiteral.Value = Value;
    return StringLiteral;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I cant believe I didn't see that!

Answer (score 3):

How can any of that work? Your method returns a type `Expr` but you are returning different types within each of the `if` statements.

The issue is that you're missing a `return` in this block:

```
if (this.tokens[this.index] is Text.StringBuilder)
{
    string Value = ((Text.StringBuilder)this.tokens[this.index++]).ToString();
    StringLiteral StringLiteral = new StringLiteral();
    StringLiteral.Value = Value;
    return Value;
}
```

You should add a return at the end of this method too.

Comment: Most likely `StringLiteral`, `IntLiteral` and `Variable` are all subclasses of `Expr`, so actually this should work.

Comment: Yeah, I had guessed as much however if this is the case the code could be made a **lot** more readable.